# Converting Google Maps Lat Long to Square meter area

Tags: area, formula, calculate-geometry

I want to convert a set of 5 Lat Long (Directly taken from Google Maps) into Sq Meter area.

As 5 points are there I have found the formula on [Converting Longitude and Latitude Coordinates to Square Miles?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/8495/converting-longitude-and-latitude-coordinates-to-square-miles?newreg=38f90fbe57394ae494e8ce56c3cdca2b)

```
area = rad(x2 - x1) * (2 + sin(rad(y1)) + sin(rad(y2))) + rad(x3 - x2) * (2 + sin(rad(y2)) +
+ sin(rad(y3))) + rad(x4 - x3) * (2 + sin(rad(y3)) + sin(rad(y4))) +
+ rad(x5 - x4) * (2 + sin(rad(y4)) + sin(rad(y5)))

area = abs(area * 6378137.0 * 6378137.0 / 2.0)
```

but this formula is not giving me the correct area.

I am putting the latitude in `x` & Longitude in `y`
also as i vary the digits after decimal places it changes the answer (obviously)
(ex. `20.011619`, `73.762870` have `6` digits after decimal)

So what is the correct method to use this formula with lat, long? Do I want to convert lat-long into another measure to get the area correctly?

Comment: Usually, x = longitude, and y=latitude. No comment on the formula you use or the answers/comments in the URL link.